# C# Replacing Captured String With Patterns?

Tags: c#, regex, replace, pattern-matching

as you can see code is to find a value and replace it but I want to be able to find 5 other similiar patterns from the same file which is kinda complicated the way the ini file is built. Any sort of "lead" or help would be helpful.

What I have managed to do so far is changing either the **last** **DeadZone=0.1** and the **first one** but I want it to override all these **6** at the same time when I choose my input value.

/Beginner

And here is the **TAInput.ini**

```
[TAGame.PlayerInput_TA]
MouseSensitivity=10
TapTime=0.5
DoubleTapTime=0.25
GamepadDeadzone=0.1 // <-- Should not be captured either but haven't been so far.
GamepadLookScale=20
KeyboardAxisBlendTime=0
GamepadDeadzones=( Type=IPT_360, Key=XboxTypeS_RightTriggerAxis, DeadZone=0.1 )
GamepadDeadzones=( Type=IPT_360, Key=XboxTypeS_LeftTriggerAxis, DeadZone=0.1 )
GamepadDeadzones=( Type=IPT_PS4, Key=XboxTypeS_RightTriggerAxis, DeadZone=0.1 )
GamepadDeadzones=( Type=IPT_PS4, Key=XboxTypeS_LeftTriggerAxis, DeadZone=0.1 )
GamepadDeadzones=( Type=IPT_XBOX_ONE, Key=XboxTypeS_RightTriggerAxis, DeadZone=0.1 )
GamepadDeadzones=( Type=IPT_XBOX_ONE, Key=XboxTypeS_LeftTriggerAxis, DeadZone=0.1 )

[ProjectX.ControlPreset_X]
```

And here is the **Form1.cs**

```
       try
        {

            const string FILENAME = "TAInput.ini";
            string text = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            const string DEADZONE = @"DeadZone=0.(?<Ratio>[\d\.]+)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(text, DEADZONE, RegexOptions.Multiline);

            if (match.Success)
            {
                int index = match.Groups["Ratio"].Index;
                int length = match.Groups["Ratio"].Length;

                text = text.Remove(index, length);
                text = text.Insert(index, nudInput.Value.ToString() + "" + "\n");


                File.WriteAllText(FILENAME, text);
                Process.Start(FILENAME);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No");
        }
```

Comment: Consider using Regex.Matches, and a foreach, assuming that the replacement string is the same length. Or easier just using Regex.Replace, if you're not *really* interested in the result of that 'if(match.Success)' test.

Comment: Thanks for your tip I will try figure it out =]

Comment: Assuming you are replacing them all with the same value, `Regex.Replace` is your friend. If there are differing values, depending on what drives the differences, the `Regex.Replace` that takes a replacement lambda is what you need.

Comment: Yes @NetMage I think that's what I am trying to go for now, still slow "in terms of coding" =] thanks for the tip :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Regex.Replace` when you need to modify the text. You are removing the text found upon a match, and then insert a `nudInput.Value.ToString() + "\n"` - that is equal to just replacing the match with the other number. However, you must **match and *capture* what you need to keep and just match what you need to remove**. That means, you do not need that named capture.

Use

```
try
{
    const string FILENAME = "TAInput.ini";
    string text = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
    const string DEADZONE = @"(DeadZone=0\.)\d[\d.]*";
    var result = Regex.Replace(text, DEADZONE, $"$1{nudInput.Value.ToString()}\n");
    File.WriteAllText(FILENAME, text);
    Process.Start(FILENAME);
}
catch
{
     MessageBox.Show("No");
}
```

Here,

- `(DeadZone=0\.)` - Capturing group 1 (later referred with with `$1`): matches and captures `DeadZone=0.` literal substring
- `\d[\d.]*` - matches a digit, and then 0+ digits and/or dots.

If you still insist on your approach, it is too hacky and fragile. The point is that you need to match the number that is not the same as the one you replace with and you need to check the whole string for a match before each subsequent replacement:

```
    try
    {
        const string FILENAME = "TAInput.ini";
        string text = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

        Regex DEADZONE = new Regex($@"DeadZone=0\.(?!{nudInput.Value.ToString()}\b)(?<Ratio>\d[\d.]*)");
        int pos = 0;
        while (DEADZONE.IsMatch(text, pos)) 
        {
            Match match = DEADZONE.Match(text);
            int index = match.Groups["Ratio"].Index;
            int length = match.Groups["Ratio"].Length;
            pos = index+nudInput.Value.ToString().Length+1;
            text = text.Remove(index, length);
            text = text.Insert(index, $"{nudInput.Value.ToString()}\n");
        }
        File.WriteAllText(FILENAME, text);
        Process.Start(FILENAME);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No");
    }
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/uWiwMo).

Comment: I cannot thank you enough =] Thanks for explaining a lot more into detail I have gotten way better understanding of it now. Thanks again